# Rails/SQL - How to filter by distinct value in a group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, count, distinct, having-clause

I'm working in Rails, but an answer in SQL is equally helpful. Let's say I have a table of Users and a table of Purchases. I want to find the Users who have only ever bought Item A. I was hoping to use a query along the lines of:

`User.joins(:purchases).group(:id).having("DISTINCT(item) = 'A'").pluck(:id)`

This is a simplification of the question I need to answer, but this grouping issue is my main roadblock. For that reason, I'm hoping for an answer that is logically very similar, as other workarounds would likely not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work in Rails?

```
User.joins(:purchases).group(:id).having("MIN(item) = MAX(item) AND MIN(item) = 'A'").pluck(:id)
```

This phrase as: there is only one distinct value (since `MIN()` and `MAX()` are equal), that is `'A'`.

Alternatively:

```
having("MAX(CASE WHEN item <> 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0")
```

Which would stand for: no other value than `'A'`.

Comment: Thanks! The first approach worked. As a side note, I was in unique situation where I was  looking for nil/null as the distinct value. In situations where the whole group nil, MIN returns nil (so does MAX I assume). So I can get away with just "MIN(item) is null"

Answer (score 1):

In `having` you can use only aggregate functions (e.g. `having count(id) > 2`) or expressions on columns you did the grouping on e.g. `having("id > 1")`.

So depending on your db you may try to find an aggregate function that identifies existence of item in the grouping per id.
For PostgreSql that would be something like (haven't tested):

```
...
GROUP BY id
HAVING 'A' = ANY(ARRAY_AGG(item))
```